# Jquery Pagination with different URL's

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I am looking to build a single page with 1000+ pages, dynamically generated from a database. One row in the db = 1 page.
I'd like the navigation to load a different, initially hidden  with jQuery, and I believe I'll be ok doing so, however I'm also hoping for each individual post/div to be accessible with a direct URL, for example site.com/page.php?page=1

Is there a way to make the url change onclick, along with the div? This way, if I had a facebook share button, it would actually share a specific post, and not just the same static page.

Thanks!

Comment: Both the share and the like buttons provide a URL parameter for the button to share, so you don't really need to change the address bar to share a different url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery plugin BBQ http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that! Is this the only way?

Comment: Maybe not ! But this way is quite nice, look at all the examples, websites like http://grooveshark.com/ uses that technique and it works quite well.